# Macro from excel to individual word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I am try to make my first mail merge macro but I don´t know how. 
Can somebody help me? I need to generate an individual document from excel to word document, save it with the name of value in cell "A2" and then close word. Is it possible?

```
The word template path is: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\all1.docx

The excel file path is: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\source.xlsm
```

Source to mail merge is sheet *Mailmerge*

Answer (score 0):

if i understand it correctly, you would like to save the worksheet to a MS word file? If yes, you could just use the saveAs function in excel-vba. you could record a macro then save the worksheet and viola, you now have the code :) just edit it..

Comment: No, I have excel file and into excel a i have a worksheet "Mailing" with several rows. Also i want to create a word document using my word template via mail merge macro in excel.